# Operator << and inheritance/composition

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I've found myself in a bit of trouble trying to overload operator<< correctly. I've searched around other questions about it, but none of the answers seemed to fit this one, so here it is:
I have a class (Register) that stores specimens of another class(subclasses of Film, which is abstract). The overloaded operator << for Register should put all the data stored in each Film type element on screen through the ostream class.Here's the code:

```
class Register{                                             
    private:
    int elementNum;
    Film* pData;
    };
    ostream &operator<<(ostream & os,const Register &v);
```

These are in the header, operator << in the cpp:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream & os,const Register &v){
    for(int i=0;i<v.elementNum;i++){
os<<v.pData[i].print()<<endl;
}
return os;
    }
```

Problem is, this way i cannot access the private variables of Register. So I tried putting the overaloaded operator<< as a member of Register, but then the compiler tells me the function must take only one argument. Last, if I remove ostream& os from the parameters, it tells me the function needs two arguments. So i would be interested in a solution where the information stored in pData can be put on screen efficiently with operator <<. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to define a member function or a free function?  You seem to have a mixture of both in the above code.

Comment: make `operator<<` a `friend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `operator<<` as a friend if access to `Register` implementation (private data) has to be granted:

```
class Register{                                             
    private:
    //...
    friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream & os,const Register &v);
};

std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream & os,const Register &v) {
    for( int i=0; i<v.elementNum; i++){
        os << v.pData[i].print() << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Friend function has access to all private ( as well as protected and public) data of a class that declared a friend.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 11.3/1 says

Friends

> A friend of a class is a function or class that is given permission to
>   use the private and protected member names from the class. A class
>   specifies its friends, if any, by way of friend declarations. Such
>   declarations give special access rights to the friends, but they do
>   not make the nominated friends members of the befriending class.

**§** 11.3/2

> Declaring a class to be a friend implies that the names of private and
>   protected members from the class granting friendship can be accessed
>   in the base-specifiers and member declarations of the befriended
>   class.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem with the operator. It prints out the data needed, but only the parts of the superclass Film, the data specific to subclasses are not shown. I've done operator << for all classes, does "virtual" work for these functions too, so the subclasses are presented adequately?

Comment: print has to be a virtual function

Comment: Print turned out not to work in the way it should be, but using os<<v.pData[i] does the job. It just cannot see the parts of the sublasses.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `operator<<` a friend of the class. You can read it up [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/output-operator.html).

Comment: -1 Sorry, in relation to all the other answers, yours is pretty poor regarding code samples. Though your answer is correct in principle ...

Comment: His was the only one that provided a link to documentation, which merits an up-vote. Writing the code for them isn't necessary to explain it.

Comment: @greek letters: you want code? Find it [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/output-operator.html), long-time verified and correct. Ever heard about trying to avoid [code repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_code)?

Comment: @RobK: thanks for the upvote :-D ... not that it really matters ... ;-)

Comment: Your answer wasn't wrong or misleading in anyway, so down-voting it IMO pollutes the voting system.

Comment: strictly speaking, by upvoting you also contributed to the pollution, since my rep is now +8 (instead of the +-0 it would have been without the downvote) ... again, not that it really matters ;-) ... answering simple questions as this one is really nothing you can pride yourself on.

Comment: @davidhigh Technically that means you should have been posting a possible duplicate link as comment and close vote (which you can't yet regarding the latter). But your link points outside SO, wich wouldn't be accepted then. (Any problems with greek letters BTW?)

Answer (score 1):

You could make `operator<<` a `friend` of class `Register` see code below:

```
class Register{                                             
    private:
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream & os,const Register &v);
    int elementNum;
    Film* pData;
};
```

Thus, `operator<<` will have access to class `Register` private members.

Answer (score 1):

To access the private members of `Register`, make `operator<<` a `friend function`:

```
class Register{                                             
    private:
    int elementNum;
    Film* pData;
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream & os,const Register &v);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the OS-Operator in a project like this:

**XYZ.h file**

> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Liwanze& arg);

**XYZ.cpp file**

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Liwanze& arg) {
string area = "";
if (arg.loc == 1)
    area = "Buxtehude";
if (arg.loc == 2)
    area = "Bangladesch";
if (arg.loc == 3)
    area = "Zimbabwe";
if (arg.loc == 4)
    area = "Bronx";
os << arg.name << " [" << area << "] ";
return os;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

or if you wish to avoid polluting your class with unwanted friends, defer the formatting to a public member of Register.

```
class Register{                                             
public:
    void writeTo(std::ostream& os) const {
        for( int i=0; i<elementNum; i++){
            os << pData[i].print() << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    //...
};

std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream & os,const Register &v) {
    v.writeTo(os);
    return os;
}
```

If you make the writeTo function defer to a protected virtual function, then operator<< will work on anything derived from Register, even in a multi-threaded environment.

```
class Register{                                             
public:
    // public non-polymorphic interface...
    void writeTo(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "any header information\n" << endl;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> myLock(_myInternalMutex);  // in MT environment
        handleWriteTo(os);  // defer to protected polymorphic implementation
    }

protected:
    virtual void handleWriteTo(std::ostream& os) const {
        for( int i=0; i<elementNum; i++){
            os << pData[i].print() << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    //...
};

std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream & os,const Register &v) {
    v.writeTo(os);
    return os;
}
```